# How to write unit tests for functions accessing HiveMetastoreClient in scala?

Tags: scala, hive

If there are any generally accepted techniques or libraries to test functions that using **HiveMetastoreClient**?

For example my function use `hmc.getTable(dbNameSNP, tableName)` or `hmc.createTable(table)`. How can I test this, without a hadoop cluster, or a HIVE instance?

I find [hiveRunner](https://github.com/HiveRunner/HiveRunner), but I'm not sure that this is the best way out, given that the library is not written in scala.

Ideally, I would like HIVE to be created in memory during the execution of tests, filled with data from scripts (for example, creating schemas, tables, entering some data) and at the moment when the tests are over, it ceases to exist.